# How to code this one using PHP Looping Structure?

Tags: php, loops

**How can i code the corresponding divisible values from a given number from the user that only have one input-box to be used?**

***For example the user input 20 in the input-box***

***Output should display like this***

The divisible value of **20** are:
**1
2
4
5
10
20**

Comment: Retrieve the value, use a loop to check the divisors. Hint: the modulus operator can help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem. You should try first for such types of issues.

Here is an example answer, upgrade it more like increasing `$i` and dynamic your `input value` and others.

```
$divisible_val = '';
for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++){
    if((20 % $i) == 0){
        $divisible_val .= $i.' ';
    }
}

echo 'The divisible value of 20 are: '.$divisible_val;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Take HTML like:

<input type="text" onkeyup="divisible(this.value)">
<br>
<div id="showDivisibel"></div>

and add javascript function like:

function divisible(val)
    {
        var divisible_val = '';
       for(i=1;i<=val;i++)
       {
        if((val % i) == 0){
          divisible_val += i +' ';
        } 
        
       }   
      $("#showDivisibel").text("The divisible value of "+val+" are:"+ divisible_val);
    }
```